# SQL # Sign Usage as a Postfix

Tags: sql

So I am reading a text on SQL to learn it.

These authors (*and this may be specific to these authors,* but also may be an important concept to understand) use a # sign after some fields.  I cant understand why.

For example for a set of tables in an early example.

> First line is Table Name the rest are fields, Further the only thing I changed was replacing a key symbol with (key) and there were boxes around them, but that's the sum of the information.

---

```
SECTIONS (table name)
course# (key)
section# (key)
teacher#
num_students
```

---

I am referring to ***course#*** and ***section#*** .Remaining tables: for completeness, but doesnt add anything.

---

```
ENROLLS
course# (key)
section# (key)
student# (key)
grade

TEACHERS
teacher# (key)
teacher_name
phone
salary

COURSES
course# (key)
course_name
department
num_credits

STUDENTS
student# (key)
student_name
address
city
state
zip
gender
```

---

The text is  **A Visual Introduction to SQL** by David Chappell and J Harvey Trimble Jr.

I have a physical copy so I cant easily put up pictures.

I have thought- maybe these are 'numeric" fields but `zip` is not `zip#`, or maybe they are primary keys elsewhere- in their respective table.  The example above I have all the tables shown.

---

disclaimer:

Its not explained in the text.  Ive searched google, though forgive me if someone comes up with an easy a google result.  YMMV obviously, and I have also searched here, and while I found a similar one, It dealt with *prefixed* '#' not **postfixed** #.

Comment: yea thats what I read in the similar post.  But nothing follows in this case.  Its just a name#.  I thought it was perhaps a specific naming convention or style convention.

Comment: "*But nothing follows in this case*" Huh? In your examples, they each are appended with ` (note)`. How do you square this statement with this fact?

Comment: Well I mentioned **I** added (key)  In reality there is a key icon /graphic that preceeds it.  That was my way of including that. While you're close, and this could be due to how they did it, in the first table there does exist *teacher#* and none of MY notes following,  Or maybe it is meant to represent keys, and **teacher#** with out the key icon is an error in the text.

Comment: so to be clear, (key) is not a comment. I added it to make a text version of the graphic I am seeing,

Comment: A `#` is not a valid identifier character in ANSI/ISO SQL. (And has nothing to do with comments.)

Comment: I can't see how using a non-alpha symbol such as a hash/pound sign is anything but bad practice and imho devalues the usefulness of this book, especially as it's supposed to be for generic SQL.

Comment: Well then thats even more confusing

Answer (score 3):

They're using `#` where literally everyone else would use `Id`. `CourseId`, `SectionId`, etc. In most SQL implementations allow use of `#` in a column name if you delimit it (e.g. `[Course#]`). Don't do this. You will kick yourself every single day of using a database with garbage field names like that.

Comment: So you mean  they are indicating key fields? See the comments above for some discussion on that, but I could perhaps buy that

Comment: The # doesn't indicate anything at all. Forget it.

Comment: It pervades the entire book, I've flipped through it, but as long more experienced answerers are saying it has no meaning (or language/style specific meaning that's of any value- forgetting about it is what I'll do- that seems to answer the question adequately

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL `#` is invalid in an identifier, but e.g. Oracle or DB2 do allow it (if it's not the first character) without the need to quote the identifier.

In my experience, it is usually used as an abbreviation for "number", so `course#` is essentially a short way of writing `course_number`